# WMSGetFeatureInfo not showing in Firefox and chrome

Tags: openlayers-2, open-source-gis, wms, getfeatureinfo

This code set works for me in IE but not in Firefox and chrome.What is the problem? Map is showing in all browsers ,but when i click on point of map nothing showing in  Firefox and chrome.

Welcome any idea!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css" type="text/css">
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var map;
 function init() {
 map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {
 projection: 'EPSG:5235',
 maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(105097.88755998248, 181965.81596899,
 107146.57905998248, 183739.10926899),
 maxResolution: 156543.0339,
 units: 'm'
 })

var wms1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('OpenLayers      WMS','http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms',{layers: 'sac:Luse'},{});
var highlight = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Highlighted Features", {displayInLayerSwitcher: false, isBaseLayer: false });

    map.addLayers([wms1,highlight]); 

    info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms', 
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });
    map.addControl(info);
    info.activate();

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
  if(!map.getCenter()){
  map.zoomToMaxExtent();
  }
  }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  <h1 id="title">Feature Info in Popup</h1>

  <div id="tags">
    WMS, GetFeatureInfo, popup
  </div>

  <p id="shortdesc">
    Demonstrates the WMSGetFeatureInfo control for fetching information
    about a position from WMS (via GetFeatureInfo request).  Results
    are displayed in a popup.
  </p>

  <div id="map_element" class="smallmap"></div>

  <div id="docs"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetFeatureInfo Request with GeoServer and OpenLayers.loadURL Not Working](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19580/getfeatureinfo-request-with-geoserver-and-openlayers-loadurl-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But this is not proxy problem. Reasons were commented below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, and i removed from OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud the FrameCloud part. Also I added a line (i modified for your implementation)

```
layerUrls: ['http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms'],
```

after

```
url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms',
```

which should be modified by eliminating 'sac'.

Now i get the pop-up but not the content i want. But it is a small step ahead.

Mihai

Answer (score 3):

can you try adding `proxyhost` for getting information? i am not sure proxy host will solve this problem, but it is useful to try and dont forget adding defination of variables, sometimes they really being big problem...

```
var info;
```

and proxyhost:

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
```

some information about proxyhost you can read [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost).

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i am using same port.I use tomcat and geoserver in 8080 port.So i think this is not a proxy problem.

Comment: Ohh it woks in IE after removing duplicated /HTML tag but not works GETfeature part in firefox or chorme.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is localhost - change it to the IP address (or web address) of the machine and it works OK -just fixed the same problem - now works in all 3 browsers.  Chrome and Firefox obviously deal with these differently than IE.